# correct Inheritance/class structure

Tags: c++

i want to write a library for linear program solving. Thereby several solvers such as cplex or gurobi are used. What i already have is an interface for each of them (all containing the same functions wrapping them to solver specific code).

Now I want to have a class 'LinearProgram' which can be instantiated e.g. by LinearProgram("cplex") which then invokes the cplex solver.

My first idea was to use a super class 'solver' which is a base class of all solver interfaces containing the respective functions as virtual declarations. But then I get an abstract class which can not be instantiated.
So in LinearProgram i wanted to have a variable Solver which is instantiated depending on the string given in the constructor.

I'm sure a proper solution is quite obvious, but all I can think about in the moment is not satisfying.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use your solver superclass idea, instantiate only subclasses, and don't use the superclass by value (use pointers and references only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This illustrates what you describe:

```
class Solver {
...abstract base
};

class SolverFactory {
public:
    Solver* NewSolverWithName(const std::string& pSolverName);
};

class LinearProgram {
public:
    LinearProgram(const std::string& pSolverName) :
      d_solver(SolverFactory::NewSolverWithName(pSolverName)) {
    }
private:
    some_auto_pointer<Solver> d_solver;
};

class cplex_Solver : public Solver {
...
    static std::string Name();
};

Solver* SolverFactory::NewSolverWithName(const std::string& pSolverName) {
    if (pSolverName == cplex_Solver::Name()) {
      return new cplex_Solver();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't have the factory class be separate. I would have a static factory method in the `Solver` class.

Comment: @Omnifarious in actuality, the better approach for a given problem depends on a lot of things. but true in some cases +1. there are many things i would do differently, if written as production code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This seems to be a nice solution for my problem. But I have a last short question concerning the implementation: I have the 'solver' base class and the 'CplexSolver' etc solver classes. I added a static function  `static solver* NewSolverWithName(const std::string& pSolverName) {
  if (pSolverName == CplexSolver::Name()) {
   return new CplexSolver();
  }
 }`

Comment: But then I always get the error messages: src/solver/solver.hpp: In statischer Elementfunktion »static solver* solver::NewSolverWithName(const string&)«:
src/solver/solver.hpp:44:22: Error: »CplexSolver« not declared
src/solver/solver.hpp:45:15: Error: expected type-specifier before »CplexSolver«
src/solver/solver.hpp:45:15: Error: »int*« can not be converted to »solver*« in return statement src/solver/solver.hpp:45:15: Error: expected »;« before »CplexSolver«
src/solver/solver.hpp:45:27: Error: »CplexSolver« not declared in this scope   Thanks for your helpt and sorry for bad highlighting

Comment: @user1801173 it's circular dependency -- move the definition of `solver::NewSolverWithName` to solver.cpp.

Comment: @justin sorry, i did this but still i get the same errors. I would be grateful for another hint. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for two different design patterns combined.

The first is the [Envelope Letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729905/changing-behavior-of-an-object-at-runtime) pattern, and the second is the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Keep on with the base class that you currently have and make a derived class that simply forwards the call to an embedded pointer to the base class. The derived class is now something you can freely pass around by value.

The base class could also contain a static member function that returns a pointer to the base class. This static member function would allow you to instantiate a derived class by using a string name to look it up. That provides a convenient way to select an algorithm at runtime.

But people who knew which derived class (which strategy) they wanted could just create one with 'new' and stuff it inside an instance of the envelope class.

You can optionally do away with the envelope class if you decide to just use a `shared_ptr` to the base class instead.